# How can I run a SAS script on AWS Instance directly from the Command Line

Tags: amazon-web-services, sas, command-line-interface

I have been using SAS on AWS MarketPlace, however it always fires up SAS Studio Web IDE, which is not very hand - I would like to run a SAS script directly from the Command Line once I have ssh'ed into my instance, something like:
$nohup sad-server my_sas_script.sas &

How can I go about doing this? many thanks

Comment: How did you install SAS?  Did you deploy a VM image?  In particular, are you running a full (licensed, paid) installation, or is this SAS University Edition or similar?

Comment: hi @Joe thanks for your input- I am using SAS university edition, thanks for your help, really struggling with this!

Comment: I don't think SAS UE is designed for this. You can with a full installation but using a thin client like SAS Studio does have limits. Given the licensing this seems fair.

Comment: It's not possible to SSH into a machine running SAS UE.